# If $G$ acts on $X$ then $\psi: X\to X$ is a bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-actions

I would appreciate if you could please express your opinion on this proof. I don't know how else this proof can be done.

**Theorem**: If $G$ acts on $X$ then $\psi: X\to X$ defined by $\psi_g(x)=g\cdot x$ is a bijection for all $g\in G$.

**Proof**: If $x=y$ then $\psi_g(x)=g\cdot x = g\cdot y=\psi_g(y)$, thus $\psi_g$ is injective. Since $|im(\psi_g)|=|X|$, $\psi_g$ is bijective.

Comment: This only works for finite groups.  Hint: can you find the inverse map?

Comment: $\psi_g(x)=g\dot x$ should be $\psi_g(x)=g\cdot x$, that is `cdot` not `dot`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr you mean finite $X$, I believe.

Comment: consider the map $\psi_{g^{-1}}$

Comment: @EPS Yes, that is indeed what I mean.  Thanks.

Comment: How does finiteness matter at all here?

Comment: @GeorgLehner The original claim is true in general (that $x\mapsto gx$ is always a bijection $X\to X$ whenever $g\in G$ and $G$ acts on $X$), but the argument given (injective endofunction $\Rightarrow$ bijection) is only valid for finite sets.

Comment: I see. It would have never occured to me to prove it this way, since the inverse is practically given. One could add the line, that for $x \in X$ the element $ g^{-1} \cdot x$ will be mapped to it; but then you could just write down the inverse map in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\psi_g(x)=\psi_g(y)$ then $gx=gy$. Then, applying $\psi _{g^{-1}}$ and using the associativity of the action, we have

$$\psi _{g^{-1}}(gx)=\psi _{g^{-1}}(gy)\Rightarrow g^{-1}(gx)=g^{-1}(gy)\Rightarrow (g^{-1}g)x=(g^{-1}g)y\Rightarrow x=y$$

so $\psi_g$ is injective.

If $x\in X$, then, again, using associativity, we have $\psi _g(g^{-1}x)=x$ which shows that $\psi _g$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Of course if $x=y$, then $\psi_g(x)=\psi_g(y)$! This is true for any function. What you need to show for injectivity is the converse of this, that is, if $\psi_g(x)=\psi_g(y)$, then $x=y$.

The second part about comparing cardinalities is correct (for finite sets $X$), but needs to be justified.